# HTML email templates for SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template

A client has contacted me asking to develop a set of templates for use with Salesforce Marketing Cloud. After many hours of searching, I'm left scratching my head.

Though I've never heard of Salesforce, I've written many HTML email templates over the years, and have been able to easily incorporate specific code for CRM-like platforms such as MailChimp and SendInBlue without many issues thanks to well-written and readily available documentation.

Can I simply build a standard HTML email and swap out or add certain tags to make them SFMC compatible? I can't find any clear documentation other than guides to using some clunky content builder. What am I missing here?

Comment: I am honestly shocked that you have not heard of SF before. It is a giant in the industry. As to your question, by template do you mean a simple PasteHTML 'static' email or something that you would create as an actual template in SFMC that would then let them move content blocks into different slots in the template via Content Builder?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to Salesforce Marketing Cloud, you should definitely start using Content Builder, especially since the Classic editor is getting close to it's end of life.

[This page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_content_builder.htm&type=5) lists a number of links, with valuable information on how to build emails using it. Especially [these videos](http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/Oxi0toiCRGmgh98EGhKsOw) give a quick, but good, overview of the features within the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this page](https://pages.exacttarget.com/mobile-inbox) for some best practices around email and template for Salesforce Marketing Cloud.